# DjangoRestFramework - How to add relational field to serializer without overriding it?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is my model:

```
class UserExtended(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    message = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)
```

It has a OneToOneField relationship with the default Django User model. This is my UserSerializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    message = serializers.CharField(source='userextended.message')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password', 'email', 'message',)

        extra_kwargs = {
                    'password': {
                        'write_only': True,
                    },
                    'email': {
                        'required': True,
                    }
                }
```

The problem with this is that now DRF thinks that the `message` field is required, even though I have `blank=True` and `null=True` in my model.

1) How do I add the `message` field to the serializer without overriding it?

OR

2) Is there a way for me to check how the `message` field would look if DRF serialized it by default (i.e. if I did not override it / if UserExtended had it's own serializer)? That way when I do override it, I can make it the exact same as how DRF would originally make it if `UserExtended` had a serializer.

What I mean by #2 is, generally DRF will automatically add `required=False` to the `message` serializer field (because `blank=True` and `null=True` in my model field) if I was serializing `UserExtended` (it might also automatically add something else as well which I do not know). However, because in my current situation (I cannot just add `message` to the list of fields and I can only do it by overriding it and using `source`), I don't know what else DRF would have automatically added other than the `required=False` to the serializer.

Comment: [Required actually defailts to `True`.](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#required)

Comment: @Ivan Sorry, what I meant was that DRF would add `required=False` to my `message` serializer field (if I was serializing `UserExtended`) because the `message` field in my model has `null=True blank=True`.

Answer (score 0):

@ivan response is correct.
DRF doesn't set to required=False because it has more possibilities than Django forms do.

Django considers a blank field to be a null input because there's no way forms can distinguish between a null value or an empty string.

However, with API it's a bit different:

1. {}
2. {'name': None}
3. {'name': ''} -
4. {'name': 'myname'}

The four are a different use case for API while 1, 2 and 3 appear to be the same with HTML forms. Therefore we need a finer grained to see which use case are allowed with API.

blank=True will allow #3/#4, null=True will allow #2/#4 and required=True will only reject #1.

Comment: Right, makes sense. Regardless though, how would I add a relational field to a serializer without overriding the field?

Comment: Use extra_kwargs (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#additional-keyword-arguments)

Comment: Can you show how I can accomplish what I need to using the `extra_kwargs`? I read what you linked to and from my understanding, extra_kwargs just maps existing field names to keyword arguments, but what I want is to be able to add a relational field to a serializer without overriding it.

Comment: In your use case, you can't. This is because you are spanning a relation and making it look as if it was "flat" therefore DRF won't handle that automatically. The only case where this may happen is by using SlugRelatedField where you provide a unique field as an alternative to the primary key.

Comment: And not that you're not overriding neither the serializer nor the field. As stated above, you're defining a new field that wouldn't just exist otherwise.